# Box instead of Fill between two plots?

Tags: pine-script, tradingview-api

I have a pretty simple script and in two areas I have levels that I have a fill function to set them apart. Using fill however means its only shaded as the bars close. It makes them useless in the first 5-10mins of trading as they are barely visible.
I would like to just use box extend right between those plots.

The second issue is all plots come from the first candle close of the day as I grab the Open to plot them off of.

```
//@version=5
indicator('AutoLevels', overlay=true)

atr = ta.atr(14)
current_day_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', open[0], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
atr_value_at_current_day_open = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, 'D', atr[1], lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)




//Multiples for each input

mult2 = input(.236)
mult3 = input(.382)
mult5 = input(.618)
mult6 = input(.786)
mult7 = input(1.236)
mult8 = input(1.382)
mult9 = input(1)

//u => Math for upper bands

u_mult2 = current_day_open + atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult2
u_mult3 = current_day_open + atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult3
u_mult5 = current_day_open + atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult5
u_mult6 = current_day_open + atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult6
u_mult7 = current_day_open + atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult7
u_mult8 = current_day_open + atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult8
u_mult9 = current_day_open + atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult9


//l => Math for lower bands


l_mult2 = current_day_open - atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult2
l_mult3 = current_day_open - atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult3
l_mult5 = current_day_open - atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult5
l_mult6 = current_day_open - atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult6
l_mult7 = current_day_open - atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult7
l_mult8 = current_day_open - atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult8
l_mult9 = current_day_open - atr_value_at_current_day_open / 2 * mult9

//Plot current days Open price
plot(current_day_open, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), linewidth=2)


//Plot for levels above open
line1 = plot(u_mult2, color=u_mult2 != u_mult2[1] ? na : color.green, linewidth=1)
line2 = plot(u_mult3, color=u_mult3 != u_mult3[1] ? na : color.green, linewidth=1)
plot(u_mult5, color=u_mult5 != u_mult5[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
line5 = plot(u_mult6, color=u_mult6 != u_mult6[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
plot(u_mult7, color=u_mult7 != u_mult7[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
plot(u_mult8, color=u_mult8 != u_mult8[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
line6 = plot(u_mult9, color=u_mult9 != u_mult9[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))

//Fill for Green Bull Bar
fill(line1, line2, color.rgb(15, 61, 16))
fill(line5, line6, color.rgb(73, 87, 73, 54))


//Plots for lower levels below Open 
line3 = plot(l_mult2, color=l_mult2 != l_mult2[1] ? na : color.red, linewidth=1)
line4 = plot(l_mult3, color=l_mult3 != l_mult3[1] ? na : color.red, linewidth=1)
plot(l_mult5, color=l_mult5 != l_mult5[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
line7 = plot(l_mult6, color=l_mult6 != l_mult6[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
plot(l_mult7, color=l_mult7 != l_mult7[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
plot(l_mult8, color=l_mult8 != l_mult8[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))
line8 = plot(l_mult9, color=l_mult9 != l_mult9[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76))

//Fill for Red Bear Bar
fill(line3, line4, color.rgb(147, 15, 15, 14))
fill(line7, line8, color.rgb(73, 87, 73, 45))

//Ensure levels show in future to give a framework. 

if barstate.islastconfirmedhistory
    line.new(bar_index, current_day_open, bar_index + 1, current_day_open, color=color.rgb(255, 255, 255), width=2, extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, u_mult2, bar_index + 1, u_mult2, color=u_mult2 != u_mult2[1] ? na : color.green, extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, u_mult3, bar_index + 1, u_mult3, color=u_mult3 != u_mult3[1] ? na : color.green, width=1, extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, u_mult5, bar_index + 1, u_mult5, color=u_mult5 != u_mult5[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, u_mult6, bar_index + 1, u_mult6, color=u_mult6 != u_mult6[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, u_mult7, bar_index + 1, u_mult7, color=u_mult7 != u_mult7[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, u_mult8, bar_index + 1, u_mult8, color=u_mult8 != u_mult8[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, u_mult9, bar_index + 1, u_mult9, color=u_mult9 != u_mult9[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, l_mult2, bar_index + 1, l_mult2, color=l_mult2 != l_mult2[1] ? na : color.red, extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, l_mult3, bar_index + 1, l_mult3, color=l_mult3 != l_mult3[1] ? na : color.red, width=1, extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, l_mult5, bar_index + 1, l_mult5, color=l_mult5 != l_mult5[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, l_mult6, bar_index + 1, l_mult6, color=l_mult6 != l_mult6[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, l_mult7, bar_index + 1, l_mult7, color=l_mult7 != l_mult7[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, l_mult8, bar_index + 1, l_mult8, color=l_mult8 != l_mult8[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
    line.new(bar_index, l_mult9, bar_index + 1, l_mult9, color=l_mult9 != l_mult9[1] ? na : color.rgb(175, 147, 76), extend=extend.right)
```

Code attached for study. All box examples I can find are based on Hi lo and not time and area based. Ive tried using the line1, line2 plots but it does nothing.  :(

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

The `box.new()` function is similar in many ways to `line.new()` function.

The main difference in your case that instead of given a single `y` value as we did with the `line` function, we'll need to give the `box` function `top` and `bottom` arguments. For example, you can add this to your code:

```
if barstate.islast
    box.new(bar_index, l_mult2, bar_index + 1, l_mult3, border_color = color.red, border_width = 1, bgcolor=color.rgb(147, 15, 15, 14), extend=extend.right)
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I am still having trouble and confidence with the context and structure of the arguments. This certainly helps me understand not only this solution but also the function itself. Much appreciated!